# Spring - Try to insert new employee to mySQL - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [null]

Tags: spring, hibernate, insert, thymeleaf

I have a problem with employee record creation in my web app (Using spring, hibernate, thymeleaf and mySQL db). Hibernate insert returns null binding parameters and failing with the following action. Could you please take a look at this? Maybe someone know what could be wrong here.

```
[nio-8090-exec-6] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
insert 
into
    temployee
    (account_status, account_type, birth_day, branch, city, department, 
email_address, first_name, full_name, home_nbr, is_manager, last_name, 
phone_number, position, position_desc, post_code, state, street, valid_from, 
valid_until) 
values
    (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2018-10-24 14:56:22.064 TRACE 14272 --- [nio-8090-exec-6]         o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] -     [null]
```

For all attributes from db insert?

My **Employee** entity class:

```
package com.project.entity;
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.project.*"})
@Entity
@Table(name="TEMPLOYEE", schema= "mydb")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")
public int employee_id;  
@Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
public String first_name;
@Column(name="LAST_NAME")
public String last_name;
@Column(name="FULL_NAME")
public String full_name;
@Column(name="EMAIL_ADDRESS")   
public String email_address;
@Column(name="PHONE_NUMBER")    
public String phone_number;
@Column(name="ACCOUNT_TYPE")    
public String account_type;
@Column(name="ACCOUNT_STATUS")  
public String account_status;
@Column(name="VALID_FROM")  
public String valid_from;
@Column(name="VALID_UNTIL") 
public String valid_until;
@Column(name="IS_MANAGER")  
public String is_manager;
@Column(name="STREET")  
public String street;
@Column(name="HOME_NBR")    
public String home_nbr;
@Column(name="CITY")    
public String city;
@Column(name="STATE")   
public String state;
@Column(name="POST_CODE")   
public String post_code;
@Column(name="BIRTH_DAY")   
public String birth_day;
@Column(name="BRANCH")  
public String branch;
@Column(name="DEPARTMENT")  
public String department;
@Column(name="POSITION")    
public String position;
@Column(name="POSITION_DESC")   
public String position_desc;

public int getEmployeeID() {
    return employee_id;
}
public void SetEmployeeID(int employee_id) {
    this.employee_id = employee_id;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return first_name;
}
public void SetFirstName(String first_name) {
    this.first_name = first_name;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return last_name;
}
public void SetLastName(String last_name) {
    this.last_name = last_name;
}
public String getFullName() {
    return full_name;
}
public void SetFullName(String full_name) {
    this.full_name = full_name;
}
public String getEmailAddress() {
    return email_address;
}
public void SetEmailAddress(String email_address) {
    this.email_address = email_address;
}
public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phone_number;
}
public void SetPhoneNumber(String phone_number) {
    this.phone_number = phone_number;
}
public String getAccountType() {
    return account_type;
}
public void SetAccountType(String account_type) {
    this.account_type = account_type;
}
public String getAccountStatus() {
    return account_status;
}
public void SetAccountStatus(String account_status) {
    this.account_status = account_status;
}
public String getValidFrom() {
    return valid_from;
}
public void SetValidFrom(String valid_from) {
    this.valid_from = valid_from;
}
public String getValidUntil() {
    return valid_until;
}
public void SetValidUntil(String valid_until) {
    this.valid_until = valid_until;
}
public String getIsManager() {
    return is_manager;
}
public void SetIsManager(String is_manager) {
    this.is_manager = is_manager;
}
public String getStreet() {
    return street;
}
public void SetStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
}
public String getHomeNbr() {
    return home_nbr;
}
public void SetHomeNbr(String home_nbr) {
    this.home_nbr = home_nbr;
}
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}
public void SetCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
public String getState() {
    return state;
}
public void SetState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}
public String getPostCode() {
    return post_code;
}
public void SetPostCode(String post_code) {
    this.post_code = post_code;
}
public String getBirthDay() {
    return birth_day;
}
public void SetBirthDay(String birth_day) {
    this.birth_day = birth_day;
}
public String getBranch() {
    return branch;
}
public void SetBranch(String branch) {
    this.branch = branch;
}
public String getDepartment() {
    return department;
}
public void SetDepartment(String department) {
    this.department = department;
}
public String getPosition() {
    return position;
}
public void SetPosition(String position) {
    this.position = position;
}
public String getPositionDesc() {
    return position_desc;
}
public void SetPositionDesc(String position_desc) {
    this.position_desc = position_desc;
}
}
```

And add employee methods:

**UserInfoConttroler** class:

```
//For add and update person both
@RequestMapping(value= "/employee/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee p){

    if(p.getEmployeeID() == 0){
        //new person, add it
        this.employeeService.addEmployee(p);
    }else{
        //existing person, call update
        this.employeeService.updateEmployee(p);
    }

    return "redirect:/employess";

}
```

**EmployeeDAOImpl** class:

```
@Transactional
 public Employee addEmployee(Employee employee) {

 entityManager.persist(employee);
 return employee;
 }

 @Transactional
 public Employee updateEmployee(Employee employee) {
 entityManager.merge(employee);
 return employee;
 }
```

And my **post form mapping** in HTML (using Thymeleaf):

```
<form method="post" name="addEmployee" id="addEmployee" 
th:action="@{/employee/add}" role="form">
    <form:hidden path="employee_id"/>
    First Name:<br>
    <input type="text" th:text="*{employee.first_name}" /><br>
    Last Name:<br>
    <input type="text" th:text="*{employee.last_name}" /><br>
    Full Name:<br>
    <input type="text" th:text="*{employee.full_name}" /><br>
    Email:<br>
    <input type="text" th:text="*{employee.email_address}" /><br>
    Phone Number:<br>
    <input type="text" th:text="*{employee.phone_number}" /><br>
    Account Type:<br>
    <input type="text" th:text="*{employee.account_type}" /><br>
    Account Status:<br>
    <input type="text" th:text="*{employee.account_status}" /><br>
    Valid from:<br>
    <input type="text" th:text="*{employee.valid_from}" /><br>
    Valid until:<br>
    <input type="text" th:text="*{employee.valid_until}" /><br>
    IS Manager?:<br>
    <input type="text" th:text="*{employee.is_manager}" /><br>
    Street:<br>
    <input type="text" th:text="*{employee.street}" /><br>
    Home number:<br>
    <input type="text" th:text="*{employee.home_nbr}" /><br>
    City:<br>
    <input type="text" th:text="*{employee.city}" /><br>
    State:<br>
    <input type="text" th:text="*{employee.state}" /><br>
    Post code:<br>
    <input type="text" th:text="*{employee.post_code}" /><br>
    Birth Day:<br>
    <input type="text" th:text="*{employee.birth_day}" /><br>
    Branch:<br>
    <input type="text" th:text="*{employee.branch}" /><br>
    Deparnment:<br>
    <input type="text" th:text="*{employee.department}" /><br>
    Position:<br>
    <input type="text" th:text="*{employee.position}" /><br>
    Position Description:<br>
    <input type="text" th:text="*{employee.position_desc}" /><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" 
value="Reset"/><br>
    </form>
```

**Adding Database table description***
Field Name   Type       NULL

EMPLOYEE_ID int(11)     NO
FIRST_NAME  varchar(20) NO
LAST_NAME   varchar(20) NO
FULL_NAME   varchar(45) YES
EMAIL_ADDRESS   varchar(60) YES UNI
PHONE_NUMBER    varchar(12) YES
ACCOUNT_TYPE    varchar(45) NO
ACCOUNT_STATUS  varchar(1)  NO
VALID_FROM  date    NO
VALID_UNTIL date    YES
IS_MANAGER  varchar(1)  NO
STREET  varchar(100)    NO
HOME_NBR    varchar(45) YES
CITY    varchar(100)    NO
STATE   varchar(100)    NO
POST_CODE   varchar(10) NO
BIRTH_DAY   date    NO
BRANCH  varchar(45) NO
DEPARTMENT  varchar(45) NO
POSITION    varchar(100)    NO
POSITION_DESC   varchar(255)    YES

Any help will be appriciated! 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please also post the table syntax with column types.

Comment: Hi, I've added a table description to the problem description.

Comment: Well, since my other suggestion didn't work, the only other thing wrong I can see is that that all the names are being sent in lowercase, while the table and fields are in uppercase. MySQL is case-sensitive when not run on Windows. Try adding the `hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers` property with a value of `true` to your configuration. If that doesn't help, we'll need an error message to even try figuring it out.

Comment: You can see from the error you posted that ACCOUNT_STATUS cannot be NULL. Add validation to check whether not null columns are filled. You need to set the status.

Comment: So none of the values are set on the entity, which means the problem is in your template. In the Thymeleaf docs they don't skip on the `name` attribute in their examples. You don't have any `name` attributes on your `input` elements, so the data doesn't get sent.

Comment: You mean something like this ? input type="text" th:text="*{account_status}" th:name="account_status"/><br>  ?